# Assigning an object of an array to sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Am new to using sql in with nodejs as i just read about sequelize and i tried to convert one of my running nodejs and mongodb application into a sql database structured application.

So i am changing my mongoose schema to sequelize model schema. So i got stucked in trying to convert the code below to work in sql.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/database');

const Auto = db.define('auto', { 
packages : {
 container: {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)
 },

 roro: {
     type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)
 }
}
});

module.exports = Auto;
```

but i kept getting this error.

```
Unrecognized datatype for attribute "auto.packages"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your model definition.
According to the docs: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#model-definition

You can't define a nested object as properties of a model.
I would recommend you to refactor your model definition according to the docs by extending `Sequelize.Model`:

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/database');

class Auto extends Model {
  // You can extend your model as you wish.
}

Auto.init(
{
    container: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)
    },
    roro: {
        type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)
    }
}, 
{
    db,        // We need to pass the connection instance
    modelName: 'auto' // We need to choose the model name
    // Any other model configurations you need.
});

module.exports = Auto;
```